# Automatically calculate value of jquery spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually how to automatically calculate subtotal depending the js spinner change, also sum them into grand total with jquery, I am newly to the jquery with operation function so any suggestion will be appreciated

Thanks

Warmly

Fiddle [>>](http://jsfiddle.net/m6csdx51/)

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="bottom-table">
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Qty / Unit</th>
            <th>Qty Needed</th>
            <th>Het ( Rp )</th>
            <th>Estimation Price</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>3DCam01</td>
            <td>3D Camera</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input class="spinner" value="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
            <td>$1500.00</td>
            <td><p class="subtotal"></p>Subtotal</td>
            <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=3DCam01" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>USB02</td>
            <td>External Hard Drive</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input class="spinner" value="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
            <td>$800.00</td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=USB02" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>wristWear03</td>
            <td>Wrist Watch</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input class="spinner" value="1" readonly="readonly"></td>
            <td>$300.00</td>
            <td>Subtotal</td>
            <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=wristWear03" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>                            
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>Total Amount</td>
            <td><a href="index.php?action=remove&code=wristWear03" class="btnRemoveAction">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>                        
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks

Warmly

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind to the spin event to get the value entered then update the DOM accordingly

```
function quantity(price, multiplier) {
    if (multiplier === 1) {
        return '$' + price.toFixed(2);
    }

    return '$' + (price * multiplier).toFixed(2);
}

$( ".spinner" ).spinner({
    min: 1,
    spin: function (event, ui) {
        var value = ui.value;
        var $target = $(event.target);
        var $priceCell = $target.parents('td').next('td');
        var $subtotalCell = $priceCell.next('td');
        $subtotalCell.text(quantity($priceCell.data('price'), value));
    }
});
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/m6csdx51/1/

notice the addition of data-price to the price cells